# In Firefox 50, what is the appropriate chrome:// URL to overlay and extend DevTools main window?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-addon-overlay

Previously, you could extend/style Firefox DevTools at `chrome://devtools/content/framework/toolbox-options.xul` with an overlay.

Now, that seems to no longer exist in Firefox 50. The Developer toolbox shows `about:devtools-toolbox` as the URL.  I'm not sure what the XUL URL of that is. What is an appropriate `chrome://` URL to *extend* or *restyle* the Firefox DevTools?

Answer (score 2):

The DevTools options moved to `chrome://devtools/content/framework/toolbox-options.xhtml` in Firefox 48. However, there are many files involved in making up the DevTools. Without detailed information as to what you are wanting to do, it is impossible to say that is the only file you will need to [overlay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Overlays) or [override](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration#override). If you are looking for the overall container of for the DevTools toolbox container, it is `chrome://devtools/content/framework/toolbox.xul`.

As is normally the case for determining things like this, you can use the [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) [DOM Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Add-ons/DOM_Inspector). I also install the [Element Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/element-inspector/) extension, which enables you to open the DOM Inspector on any element with a <kbd>Shift</kbd> + right-click. You can also open the DOM Inspector from the Menu Bar->Tools->Web Developer->DOM Inspector.

Having both of those add-ons installed makes it easy to find out what the URL is for the DevTools options: just open the DevTools, <kbd>F12</kbd>; display the options; then open Dom Inspector by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + right-click within the DevTools options; then within the DOM Inspector select the topmost `<document>` and switch to the JavaScript Object view. The `URL` property will display the URL.

[image: Show the URL]

I also find it convenient to unpack the *omni.ja* files that come with Firefox. These are located in *[Firefox install directory]* and *[Firefox install directory]/browser/*. Prior to Firefox 48, there was also one in *[Firefox install directory]/webapprt*. I find that having these unpacked makes it easier to go exploring through the files and makes them easily available to grab a copy when needed for an [override](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration#override).  Alternately, you can go looking through the [source code](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools/client/framework). For the DevTools, they are in the *browser/omni.ja* file within the *chrome/devtools* directory.

### Official APIs

**The [DevTools API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/DevToolsAPI):**
The [DevTools API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/DevToolsAPI) is considered a work in progress.  With this API it is possible to add tabs/tools to the DevTools panel, `registerTool(toolDefinition)`, register a theme, `registerTheme(themeDefinition)`, etc.

The Add-on SDK [`dev/panel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/dev_panel) API allows you to add a panel to the DevTools [toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Tools_Toolbox).

Comment: Yes, I saw that that is now an xhtml. Unfortunately you cannot overlay an html and extend it with an overlay. What is the url of the outer xul frame so I can add a script there?

Comment: But, you should be able to `override` it. I have added the `chrome:` URL for the toolbox container to the first paragraph. This is beginning to hint at being an [XY problem](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=XY+problem). Please edit your question to describe what you are actually trying to accomplish, not just how you are trying to accomplish it.

Comment: If xhtml were possible to overlay with new controls, that would be an answer, but I don't think one can even inject a script to a xhtml from an addon with an xul and an entry in chrome.manifest. *Replacing* the xhtml doesn't seem like a great idea because no one else would be able to modify it at the same time, and updates to Firefox would leave it at an old version of that file.

Comment: By the way you don't need that DOM inspector addon, there is one in Firefox built-in Browser Toolbox now.

Comment: @noBugs, I appreciate you mentioning it. I find that both have their advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: @NoBugs, You appeared to be looking for an XUL overlay/override methodology. While they do not appear to be what you were looking for, I have added the official APIs to the answer for completeness.